# Combo field shows default value instead of display value

Tags: reactjs, combobox, jsx

So I am trying to define a combo box in React using JSX syntax. However, the UI keeps on showing me the default value instead of display value on the first render. The ComboBox is the custom React element I have in my code.

Here is the code -

```
**UI file**
export default class UI extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
        <Form horizontal>
          <ComboBox value={store.defaultValue}>
          <Option value={"internalValue1"}>{'DisplayValue1'}</Option>
          <Option value={"internalValue2"}>{'DisplayValue2'}</Option>
          </ComboBox>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

**store file**
import { observable } from 'mobx';

export default class store{
  @observable defaultValue= "internalValue1";
}
```

The following code shows internalValue1 as the combo box display value at the Initial render. How do I show DisplayValue1 itself on the first render?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the value is always set to `store.defaultValue` whenever render is called.

Have something like `onChange` in the `ComboBox` component and update the state whenever there is a change, in the constructor add the default value for the `ComboBox`

```
constructor(props) {
    const { store } = props;
    this.state = { comboBoxValue: store.defaultValue };
}

render() {
    ...
    <ComboBox
       value={this.state.comboBoxValue}
       onChange={(e) => this.setState({ comboBoxValue: e.target.value })}
    >
        <Option value={"internalValue1"}>{'DisplayValue1'}</Option>
        <Option value={"internalValue2"}>{'DisplayValue2'}</Option>
    </ComboBox>
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added the onChange event in the ComboBox component. However, it still throws an error saying it can't read the comboBoxValue property. Sorry, but new to React and JSX altogether.

Comment: You need to set the default value for the `comboBoxValue` in the state.

Comment: I tried that. But it does not work still. Keeps showing default value.

Comment: Which `ComboBox` are you using? Is it on github?

Comment: Unfortunately, its a custom one.

Comment: What's worse is the render() where the state needs to go is just using super.render(). I was referring to this page myself - 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value